# why java cannot save python program rdf RDF ontology file locally?

Tags: java, python, rdf, rdflib

I have the python program. 
all the code can work in python.

which means that I can use the python run the ontology.py and generate the myOntology.rdf locally.

here is some part of the code:

```
print"~~~~~~~~~~~generate myOntology.rdf~~~~~~~~"
gs = Graph()
graph=getRDF(Triple)
for g in graph:
    gs=gs+g   
gs.serialize(format='xml')
print gs.serialize(format='xml')   ### in java ____  OK

print "save locally???........"

print gs.serialize("myOntology.rdf",format="xml")   
##in java______Python Output: None

print gs.serialize(destination="D:\\Desktop\\myOntology.rdf",format="xml") 
##in java__ no response
print"~~finish  !!!   ~generate  myOntology.rdf~~~~~~~~"
```

however, when i use the java to call pyhton and run ontology.py. the program stoped to save the rdf locally.  Note: my java program is correct!!!

[image]

I really do not know what is the issue as the python code and java code are correct.
but when java call python to run the py, the rdf cannot be saved locally.

Comment: i would check write permission settings of whatever user java is running on your system

Comment: when i use python run the 1st python program to save the rdf file locally.  then use java to run the other python code. It works.there is no error..  In my case, i have 3 python program code. 1st python program: generate rdf (which is the myOntology.rdf), 2nd python program: compare . 3rd python program: analyse

Answer (score 1):

```
file = open("output.rdf", "w")
results.serialize(destination=file, format="xml")
file.flush()
file.close()
```

i add the file open,close.... the issue is solved. But i do not know why it works